# Frobenius Method around $x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the series created by using the Frobenius method around the differential equation $$2x^2y''+3xy'-(x^2+1)y=0$$

I need to find it around the point $x=0$. I'm totally lost, please help if you can.

Comment: I don't understand how to find the indices.

Comment: I don't understand how to calculate the indices for this equation.

Comment: Have you found the indicial polynomial? What have you done so far?